# Are weights of a neural network derivative work of the GPL-3 training framework?

Tags: gpl-3

I could not really find a satisfying answer here yet, [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/how-does-gpl-apply-to-neural-network-models) touches it but kind of reversed.

1. For example the training framework for Yolo [v7](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/tree/main) is used to train a neural network using the config (cfg) file from the repo which is licensed under GPL-3 using custom data.
2. Now the model gets exported to onnx (or tflite or any other major inference runtime) and used with inference scripts that are completely self-written (inference done by onnxruntime, especially post-processing like decoding and nms self-written).

Is (2) now derivative work and must be distributed under GPL-3 too by using the neural network weights?

Comment: The non-answer to this question is that there is no clear answer to this yet. It's going to be an evolving area of copyright law over the next few years.

Comment: It is not really answerable legally. I suspect it is probably going to be regarded as output data of a GPL program, just like mentioned in the question https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same
The other possibility, as mentioned in the first question you linked to, is that the model data are not even copyrightable, as they were not created by a human.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that is what I thought after not finding a lot of resources on this matter. Interestingly, some [Kaggle competitions](https://www.kaggle.com/c/global-wheat-detection/discussion/163433) do not allow YOLO models because of the GPL 3 License. Also the creator of Yolo v3 and v5 does not really have an [answer](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/5710). Maybe, I compile some results of my search on this later when I have time. Many thanks so far!